# How to submit patch series to Linux Mailing List with version change when only patch description has been modified from previous version?

Tags: git, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I submitted two patches with patch series. There were problems with both of the patches. 
I have to change each patch description and send them with version 2.

My question is about the patch version change.
When I change both patch description do I have to leave the old descriptions there and under "Changed from V*" write the new description?
Or I can change the descriptions of both patches and in the cover letter mention about those changes like " Modify patch description of (some patch)"?

I am wondering about these two options because. If I leave the previous description and write my new changes under  "Changed from V*" it will be too much of info. But if I change both patch descriptions and not leave anything from the previous description the reviewer will not know what to follow. The only information will be in the cover letter.

What do you think which option would be more correct to use?
Or maybe there is some other option.

Comment: Change log is not (and should not be) a part of commit message. Either in cover letter, or in individual patches, after `--- ` line describe your changes with updated commit message and, if required, patches content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use patch series with cover letter, it is always recommended to update only the cover letter of patch series i.e 0/2 with `Changes in V2`.

If I understand correctly, the patch description here you mean is commit message. If so, then you can use `git commit --amend` and edit the problem and save it.

Usually the maintainer will see the cover letter first and review the patches. To add, commit message should not carry history of changes at all if it is series.

If you are dealing with single patch, then you have to use `git format-patch --notes <SHA>` to have the history of changes.

This is the way Linux Kernel patches works!

Comment: *Paragraph 1*. By whom? It is completely maintainer-dependent. *Paragraph 2*. To edit more than 1 (last) commit, actually the use case according to OP, better to use `git rebase --interactive`. *Paragraph 4*. Why **have to**?